# ssh tunnelling explanation

Tags: ssh, x11, ssh-tunneling, xforwarding

I have a question regarding ssh tunneling. I've read this article

- http://www.popcornfarmer.com/2009/01/ssh-tunneling-tutorial/

I would like to make X forwarding work and run some X applications at home and have them displayed on a remote system:

```
 ssh -X -R 5555:localhost:22 user@remoteserver.com -N
```

On remote:

```
 ssh -X -p 5555 user@192.168.1.2
```

Then on home:

```
 //configure sshd to listen on 5555
 ssh user@remoteserver.com
 //here run some app
```

Should it work?

Comment: Please try it instead of asking if it would work.

Comment: Yes it's always best to try things and then if it doesn't work ask why.

Comment: sounds like you are doing it backwards .. the "normal" is to run in the remote and display it local.  if you want to display on remote tell us about your network it may be simple and not even need ssh.

Answer (score 8):

### I have drawn some sketches

The machine, where the ssh tunnel command is typed is called **»your host«**.

[image: ssh tunnel starting from local]

---

[image: ssh tunnel starting from remote]

### Introduction

1. local: `-L Specifies that the given port on the local (client) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the remote side.`

   `ssh -L sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **local** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from the `connectToHost` machine.
2. remote: `-R Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.`

   `ssh -R sourcePort:forwardToHost:onPort connectToHost` means: connect with ssh to `connectToHost`, and forward all connection attempts to the **remote** `sourcePort` to port `onPort` on the machine called `forwardToHost`, which can be reached from your local machine.

### Your example

Well, if you only would like to make X forwarding work, i.e. run some X applications on the computer at home and have them displayed on a remote system (let’s call it work computer, because it might be at your workplace), then you possibly don’t need an ssh tunnel at all.

#### Start X applications *without* tunnel

Can you simply ssh from the work computer to your home computer? If so, when you are *sitting on the work computer* and want to start an X application which *runs on your home computer* but *displayes on your work computer*, you have to type (on the work computer):

ssh -X homeuser@homecomputer firefox

This will start firefox on your home computer and display it on the machine where you typed this command, e.g. your work computer.

#### Hidden computer needs tunnel

This is **image number 3** of my sketches. Many times the home computer is not reachable directly from the internet, because it is behind a firewall or hidden through [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (from a router). Then you can use a tunnel.

At your *blue* home computer (`yourhost`) you type:

```
ssh -R 5555:localhost:22 remoteuser@remotehost
```

where `5555` is the green port and `22` ist the pink port in the image.

If you are now at work, at the `remotehost`, and connect to the green port `5555`, your connection is tunneled/forwarded to the pink port of your home computer’s `localhost` (i.e. your *blue* home computer itself). Now you have to type on your work computer:

```
ssh -X -p 5555 homeuser@localhost firefox
```

which will start firefox on your home computer (`yourhost`) and display it on the machine where you typed this command, e.g. your work computer (`remotehost`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the remote display that you want to forward. On remote:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ssh -X -p 5555 user@localhost # not sure why you used 192.168.1.2
```

To forward the `:0` display.

Then in that shell (now running on your home machine), run:

```
echo "$DISPLAY"
```

to find out what is the forwarded display. That will be something like `localhost:10`, which means you need to do a TCP connection on port 6010 to connect to the display `:0` on the remote machine (`:0` meaning to connect to some Unix domain socket in something like `/tmp/.X11-unix`)

Then for an application on your machine to display on the remote server's display, it's just a matter to tell them to use `localhost:10`:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:10 xlogo
```

for instance.

Note that, that's a tunnel over a tunnel.